# DB2 Convert from YYYYMMDD to Date

Tags: sql, date, casting, db2

I have a column that stores a date as char in the format 'YYYYMMDD'. Now I want to convert it to a real date.
I tried

```
select cast (DATEFIELD as DATE) as MyDate
```

But it only returns the old `YYYYMMDD` format labeled as 'DATE'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your format in yyyy/mm/dd or yyyymmdd?

Comment: The format is yyyymmdd

Comment: I don't think that there is any issue with your Query, seems okay

Comment: "convert it to a real date" Define real date?

Comment: @Matt I tried in my DB, it works fine

Comment: Try this


DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(MAX) = '20150529'
SELECT CAST(@DATE AS DATE)

Comment: In what format should the output be in this case? I want something that i can compare to the current timestamp function, for example.

Comment: When i do "DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(MAX) = '20150529' SELECT CAST(@DATE AS DATE)", I get "ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD VARCHAR.  TOKEN  WAS EXPECTED SQL Code: -199, SQL State: 42601"

Comment: What platform and version of DB2?

Comment: I think it's V10 running on some linux machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT TIMESTAMP_FORMAT("DATEFIELD",'YYYYMMDD') as "MyDate"`

Comment: On the iSeries, I'd sometimes have problems with TIMESTAMP_FORMAT and instead use TO_DATE

Answer (score 1):

This is how you convert a Normal date to an iSeries (AS/400) Date Format:
TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')) - 19000000

If you need the other way from iSeries to Normal date Format you use this:
to_date(to_char(19000000+1230721),'YYYYMMDD')

Comment: In iSeries when using a field in to_date(to_char( myField ),'YYYYMMDD'), make sure it's a valid date (not zero, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert it.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_FORMAT("DATEFIELD",'YYYYMMDD') as MyDate
  FROM <your_table>
```

Comment: this answer will alter the data table where the question is about how to get the data column converted.

Comment: @Hogan: The answer has been edited since my comment, Please take a look at edits. My commnet was relevant when there was an Alter statement.

Comment: @Hogan The question was also different, I really changed my answer since it was not relevant to the question anymore. Sorry for misguiding you.

Comment: @Asha -- ugh sorry about that, I didn't look at the history.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `CONVERT` function and the style `112` to get the output in `YYYYMMDD`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATEFIELD, 112) as MyDate
FROM yourtable
```

Or style `100` for `mon dd yyyy hh:mi`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATEFIELD, 100) as MyDate
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: I tried your second suggestion but I get: NO AUTHORIZED CONVERT NAMED  HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND SQL Code: -440, SQL State: 42884

Comment: This is sql server not db2